# Can Dataflow's frequency of (horizontal) autoscaling be changed?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I use Google's Dataflow for streaming jobs.

I use the (horizontal) autoscaling feature, and it is great to not have to worry about how many resources I have to allot.

But I have two related concerns:

1. The job monitor only acts every 10 minutes. Therefore, if a pipeline is *hammered* with messages it needs to process, scaling will not be triggered until up to 10 minutes after the high throughput began.
2. The `num_workers` flag only sets the *initial* number of workers in a pipeline. AFAICT, there is no way to set the *minimum* number of workers.

If I could either increase the *frequency* of checks to see whether more compute is needed, *or* if I could set a minimum number of workers for a pipeline, this would prevent the backlog that could be generated.

I would prefer the former (check more often) than the latter (minimum # of workers).

Is there any way to set either of these?  I could not find anything in the documentation.

Comment: Please check this https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/horizontal-autoscaling#manual. For streaming jobs, you can specify `min-num-workers`.

Comment: Thanks, you're right!!  I looked over pages and pages of documents, but didn't see this one.

Comment: The flag and documentation are strange: documentation suggests I can only _update_ a job with that flag, not launch it with that flag.  But I tried launching _and_ updating, both worked.  It's also strange (annoying) that a dash `-` is used instead of underscore `_`, since they exclusively use underscore for all other flags.

Comment: Still would be great / ideal if I could ask it to re-assess more often than every 10 minutes.